# allowframebreak with a particular slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, page-breaking

I'm trying to handle a slide which is very big, so I use `allowframebreak` with that frame. It is not working in this case.

I made a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}

\section{Metodología}

\subsection{Consideraciones termodinámicas}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}  %HERE STARTS THE TROUBLE
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20,
    minimum height=2em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (react) {Reactantes};
\node [block, below of=react] (myc) {Generar microespecies y conformeros};
\node [block, below of=myc] (opt1) {Optimización (MOPAC)};
\node [block, below of=opt1] (solv) {Solvatación (programas)};
\node [block, below of=solv] (opt2) {Optimización (MOPAC)};
\node [block, left of=opt2, node distance=5cm] (metodo) {Revisar metodología};
\node [block, below of=opt2] (termo) {Cálculo termodinámico};
\node [block, below of=termo] (exp) {Contraste experiental};
\node [block, below of=exp] (decide) {¿Resultado aceptable?};
\node [block, below of=decide] (stop) {stop};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (react) -- (myc);
\path [line] (myc) -- (opt1);
\path [line] (opt1) -- (solv);
\path [line] (solv) -- (opt2);
\path [line] (opt2) -- (termo);
\path [line] (termo) -- (exp);
\path [line] (exp) -- (decide);
\path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {no} (metodo);
\path [line] (decide) -- node {sí}(stop);
\path [line] (metodo) |- (myc);


\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

You can see `framebreak` is activated.
The image, which is too long for a slide, is the next one:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you would like to break the flow-chart in two? Is it not better to draw it in a different way so that it can fit one slide?

Comment: mmm..yes what you suggest should be better, but how can i do that? @CarLaTeX

Comment: @CarLaTeX It is good enough, CarLa, i will try it now...and then accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of break the flow-chart, draw it in another way.

I've used a `tikz matrix` to let `tikz` do the node positioning for you.

```
\documentclass[handout, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\AtBeginSection[]
{%
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Tabla de contenidos}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Metodología}
\subsection{Consideraciones termodinámicas}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title} % fragile otherwise you can't use % in matrix
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define block styles
\tikzset{% use tikzset instead of tikzstyle
    block/.style ={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
        text width=4.7em, text centered, rounded corners, font={\scriptsize}, minimum height=7ex},
    line/.style ={draw, -Stealth},
    cloud/.style ={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \matrix[row sep=2ex,column sep=1em] {% 
        \node[block] (react) {Reactantes};&&&&[.8pt]\\
        \node[block] (myc) {Generar microespecies y conformeros}; &
        \node[block] (opt1) {Optimización (MOPAC)}; &
        \node[block] (solv) {Solvatación (programas)}; &
        \node[block] (opt2) {Optimización (MOPAC)}; \\
        &&& \node[block] (termo) {Cálculo termodinámico}; \\
        &&& \node[block] (exp) {Contraste experiental}; \\
        \node[block] (metodo) {Revisar metodología};
        &&& \node[block] (decide) {¿Resultado aceptable?}; & 
        \node[ellipse, draw, fill=blue!20, font={\scriptsize}] (stop) {stop};\\
    };
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (react) -- (myc);
    \path [line] (myc) -- (opt1);
    \path [line] (opt1) -- (solv);
    \path [line] (solv) -- (opt2);
    \path [line] (opt2) -- (termo);
    \path [line] (termo) -- (exp);
    \path [line] (exp) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node[very near start, above, font={\scriptsize}] {no} (metodo);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node[above, font={\scriptsize}] {sí} (stop);
    \path [line] (metodo) -- (myc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Carla, just the last question. Should it be possible to set "Revisar metodología" at same height of "Contraste experiental"? I do not understand very well matrix notation :(

Comment: @HernanProust Of course! The `matrix` notation is like a `tabular`, it is enough to move the node to the fourth line (no time at the moment, I'm at work, I'll edit my answer tonight).

Comment: @HernanProust I've edited it anyway because there was an `Overfull hbox`. I've positioned the "Revisar metodología" node at same height of the test node, I think it looks better this way. :)

Comment: @HernanProust You're welcome! It's a pleasure to help a user so collaborative!